# Differentiation and punctured neighbourhoods

Tags: real-analysis

I cannot seem to be able to solve the following apparently simple problem :
Let $f$ be defined on a neighbourhood of $c$, with $f'(c)>0$. Prove that there exists some punctured neighbourhood $N$ of $c$ such that  $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} > 0$ for $x$ element of $N$. Nothing that I have tried some close to a solution....

Comment: Hint: derivative is a limit. Use $\epsilon-\delta$ defition of limit.

Comment: I have tried this epsilon delta approach ....Still cannot do anything

Comment: Mean value theorem ?

Comment: @user247608, we only know that $f'(c)>0$. Derivative in neighbour points can not exists.

Comment: Let $\epsilon = c/2.$ Then there is $N$ such that $x\in N \implies $ the difference quotient lies in $(c/2,3c/2).$

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the existence of the derivative at c?  Let {x_n} be any sequence converging to c, no x_n==c, define a new sequence of approximations to the derivative as ( f(x_n) - f(c) ) / (x_n - c) , so for sufficiently close x_n to c the approximation can be made to be f'(c)/2 say of f'(c), hence the result. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because
$$
                \lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c) > 0,
$$
then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
             \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right| <\frac{f'(c)}{2}
$$
whenever $0 < |x-c| < \delta$. In particular,
$$
        -\frac{f'(c)}{2} < \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - f'(c) \mbox{ whenever } 0 < |x-c| < \delta \\
             0 < \frac{f'(c)}{2} < \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \mbox{ whenever } 0 < |x-c| < \delta.
$$